# Ownership question (case with immutable and mutable borrow)

Tags: utf-8, rust, ownership

I have a newbie question about ownership, I'm trying to update (+= 1) on the last bytes and print out the UTF-8 characters.
But I have mutable borrow to the String s in order to change the last byte thus I can't print it (using immutable borrow).
What would be the Rustacean way to do so?

Note: I'm aware I'm not doing it properly, I'm at learning stage, thanks.

```rust
fn main() {
    let s = vec![240, 159, 140, 145];
    let mut s = unsafe {
        String::from_utf8_unchecked(s)
    };
    
    unsafe {
        let bytes = s.as_bytes_mut();  // mutable borrow occurs here
        
        for _ in 0..7 {
            println!("{}", s);  // Crash here as immutable borrow occurs here
            bytes[3] += 1;
        }
    }
    
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

Comment: While I cannot provide more assistance right now, some tips: you are strongly advised not to use `unsafe` constructs while you're still learning, a small mistake and you'll have a very bad time; Might be worth re-reading the book on [References and Borrowing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html), and apply the knowledge to that code (see the relation between `s` and `bytes` and their lifetimes); Search Stack Overflow for the compiler's error message to see questions with similar problems.

Comment: As `bytes` is a mutable reference to `s`, you cannot use `s` while `bytes` exists.

Comment: Thanks @E_net4ofthedownvotebrigade, I'm currently reading the book and I'm into the Common Collection chapter, trying to dig into String structure and also challenge my knowledge about Reference and Borrowing as well.
I'm aware and fully understand that I can't create an immutable borrow while an existing mutable borrow exists.
I guess the underlying problem is that I don't know how to find what I want in the doc https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/primitive.str.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`std::str::from_utf8`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/fn.from_utf8.html) to make a `&str` from `bytes` to print it as a string.